# How does work webpack long term caching?

Tags: webpack

I never use this in my project, but I found this in yeoman **`webpack.make.js`**.

This code:

```
 config.plugins.push(new CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',

    // filename: "vendor.js"
    // (Give the chunk a different name)

    minChunks: Infinity
    // (with more entries, this ensures that no other module
    //  goes into the vendor chunk)
}));



   config.output = {
    // Absolute output directory
    path: BUILD ? path.join(__dirname, '/dist/client/') : path.join(__dirname, '/.tmp/'),

    // Output path from the view of the page
    // Uses webpack-dev-server in development
    publicPath: BUILD || DEV || E2E ? '/' : `http://localhost:${8080}/`,
    //publicPath: BUILD ? '/' : 'http://localhost:' + env.port + '/',

    // Filename for entry points
    // Only adds hash in build mode
    filename: BUILD ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js',

    // Filename for non-entry points
    // Only adds hash in build mode
    chunkFilename: BUILD ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].bundle.js'
};
```

Why shold we use `[hash]` and `CommonsChunkPlugin` ?
 What does it mean?

Can I get the easy example with these tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[hash]` is made of the checksum of the bundle file.

It changes when the content of the bundle changes, otherwise stays the same. This is useful for browser cache optimization – if you deploy a new version of your JS code to your server, it will have a different file name than the previous version and the browser will fetch the latest version, regardless of its cache settings.

→ [see webpack documentation on long term caching](https://webpack.github.io/docs/long-term-caching.html)

The `CommonsChunkPlugin` is used to split your bundle into different bundles to optimize load times.

Imagine you have a page A with bundle-a.js and page B with bundle-b.js. Both bundles contain the same library modules X and Y. You can create a separate chunk bundle, let's call it bundle-lib.js that is loaded on page A and B and contains library modules X and Y.

→ [see webpack documentation on code splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html)

→ [see webpack documentation on the plugin, with examples](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin)

Comment: Thank you very match for a good explanation. I understand what static files must have something hash for update, when I deploy a new version. Webpack is a very good tool for client.

Comment: Glad to help 